# Convergence/Divergence of infinite product

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, infinite-product

General condition: $(P_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of non-zero real numbers.
If $\prod_{n=0}^\infty P_n$ exists in reals and is **non-zero**, then call this infinite product convergent. Otherwise divergent.

I have proven that:

If all $(P_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are positive, then its convergence is equivalent to convergence of $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \log(P_n)$.

If further $(P_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are further greater or equal to 1, then the convergence of the product is equivalent to the convergence of $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (P_n-1)$

Now I am looking for two examples where
a)  $(P_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are reals. $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (P_n-1)$ converges but $\prod_{n=0}^\infty P_n$ diverges
b) $(P_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are reals. $\prod_{n=0}^\infty P_n$ converges but $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (P_n-1)$ diverges

I have spent a long time on this but failed to find any. I guess it requires complex analysis technique? (Which I don't know) Please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: I guess you are aware that such example cannot be found for $P_n>1$. See for example [here](http://cornellmath.wordpress.com/2008/01/26/convergence-of-infinite-products/). Maybe there are some posts at MSE, where this was shown.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I'm aware of that. I also know $P_n$ should oscillate around 1 and |log(Pn)| must not decrease monotonely.

Comment: Such Examples are given in Problems 3.8.5 and 3.8.9 in Wieslawa J. Kaczor, Maria T. Nowak: Problems in mathematical analysis: Volume 1; Real Numbers, Sequences and Series, [p.113-114](http://books.google.com/books?id=HrO6QzUHU-gC&pg=PA113).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [OP's request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324650/convergence-divergence-of-infinite-product?noredirect=1#comment705732_324650) I made my comment into an answer. I am making this CW; if someone wants to add details of the solutions, feel free to do so. (Of course, if you prefer, you can post them in a separate post, so that you are rewarded by reputation for you effort.)

Such Examples are given in Problems 3.8.5 and 3.8.9 in Wieslawa J. Kaczor, Maria T. Nowak: Problems in mathematical analysis: Volume 1; Real Numbers, Sequences and Series, [p.113-114](http://books.google.com/books?id=HrO6QzUHU-gC&pg=PA113).

**Problem 3.8.5** Set
$$a_{2n-1}=\frac1{\sqrt{n}}+\frac1n,\qquad a_{2n}=-\frac1{\sqrt{n}}, n\in\mathbb N.$$
Show that the product $\prod\limits_{n=1}^\infty(1+a_n)$ converges, although the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ diverges.

A solution is given on [p.364](http://books.google.com/books?id=HrO6QzUHU-gC&pg=PA364).

**Problem 3.8.9.** Prove that the product $\prod\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left(1+(-1)^{n+1}\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\right)$ diverges although the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac1{\sqrt{n}}$ converges.

A solution is given on [p.365](http://books.google.com/books?id=HrO6QzUHU-gC&pg=PA365).