# $\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\cdots}}}}}$ approximation

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals, infinite-product, nested-radicals

Is there any trick to evaluate this or this is an approximation, I mean I am not allowed to use calculator.

> $$\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\cdots}}}}}$$

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588414/very-common-algebra-question-made-tough

Comment: It would probably be easier to think of it if you write it as a fractional exponent: $7^\frac{1}{32}$

Comment: Actually, in general, root(n*x) is `closer` to n than x. Unless n is x. From that, if you do it an infinite number of times, x will always get to n

Comment: "The square root approximation". Good episode title for Big Bang Theory!

Comment: @user2378, please stop adding the `roots` tag.  It has nothing to do with this question.  Take a look at [the tag's description](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/roots/info).

Comment: Why does this have 41 upvotes? This is a fairly standard type of limit.

Comment: And now everybody guess what's the limit of $\sqrt{8\sqrt{8\sqrt{8\sqrt{8\sqrt{8\cdots}}}}}$.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Let $$\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7...}}}}}=x $$

Clearly, $x>0$

$$\implies x^2=7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7...}}}}}=7x$$

Now left is the proof of converge(as conversed with  Abdulh Khazzak Gustav ElFakiri)

Observe that the $r$th term $T_r$ of this infinite product is $\displaystyle7^{\left(\frac1{2^r}\right)}$

using [Convergence/Divergence of infinite product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324650/convergence-divergence-of-infinite-product), $$\sum_{0\le r<\infty}\ln(T_r)=\ln 7\sum_{0\le r<\infty}\frac1{2^r}$$ which is an infinite [Geometric Series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html) with common ratio $=\frac12$ which $\in(-1,1)$, hence  the later Series is convergent $\left(\text{ in fact }\displaystyle=\ln7\cdot\frac1{1-\frac12}\right)$, so will be the original infinite Product

Comment: $x^2-7x =0$ and hence x=7?

Comment: @user2378, what is the other root of $x^2=7x?$

Comment: other is $0$ but we cant consider that.

Comment: You didnt prove convergence

Comment: @AbdulhKhazzakGustavElFakiri, we can apply the logic heer (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324650/convergence-divergence-of-infinite-product) $$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty 7^{\frac1{2^n}}=\ln 7 \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac1{2^n}=\cdots$$

Comment: Down voter, would you mind disclosing the mistake?

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee Is the rth term here not $7^{\frac{2^r-1}{2^r}}=7(7)^{-\frac{1}{2^r}}$?

Answer (score 191):

$$\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7...}}}}}=7^\frac{1}{2}\cdot7^\frac{1}{4}\cdot 7^\frac{1}{8}\cdots=7^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\cdots}=7^{\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}}=7$$

Comment: this hints looks so fresh!! I usually do this by Mr.Labbhattacharjee's way...

Comment: Ah!! I am disappointed... This looks so nice if it was left just by writing $\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\dots}}}=7^{\frac{1}{2}}7^{\frac{1}{4}}7^{\frac{1}{8}}...$

Comment: Sorry sir, but exactly what you say

Comment: it would have been look much great if you have removed $=7^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\cdots}=7^{\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}}=7$ part...

Comment: what did help was the beginning, and this is now the complete solution of the example

Comment: I appreciate your answer! I've seen it [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/955190/find-the-value-of-sqrt10-sqrt10-sqrt10/955210#comment2174784_955210) some time ago! :-) +1

Answer (score 23):

Your expression can be written as $$7^{\frac12 + \frac14 ...}.$$

Now you can use sum of infinite GP = $\frac{a}{1-r}$ where $a$ is the first term and $r$ is the common ratio.

Thus sum $= 1$.

Your expression $=$ $7^1$ = $7$

Answer (score 16):

We need to find the value of $\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{\dots}}}}}$.
**Step 1: Let $\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\dots}}}}}=y$**
**Step 2: Square both sides.**
$$7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\dots}}}}}=y^2$$
**Step 3: Recall that $\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\dots}}}}}=y$. So:**
$$7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\dots}}}}}=7y$$
**Step 4: Rewrite the equation.**
$$7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\dots}}}}}=y^2$$
$$7y=y^2$$
$$y^2-7y=0$$
**Step 5: Solve for $y$.**
$$y^2-7y=0$$
$$y(y-7)=0$$
$$y=0, \ 7$$
It is impossible that $y=0$. So, $y=7$.
$$\displaystyle \boxed{\therefore \sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\dots}}}}}=7}$$

Answer (score 14):

Alternatively, let $a_1,\,a_2,\,a_3,\,\cdots,\,a_n$ be the following sequence
$$\sqrt{7},\,\sqrt{7\sqrt{7}},\,\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7}}},\,\cdots,\underbrace{\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{\cdots\sqrt{7}}}}}}_{\large n\,\text{times}}$$
respectively.

Notice that
$$\large a_n=7^{\Large 1-2^{-n}}$$
Hence
$$\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{\cdots}}}}}=\large\lim_{n\to\infty}\, a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\,7^{1-\Large2^{-n}}=\bbox[3pt,border:3px #FF69B4 solid]{\color{red}{7}}$$

Answer (score 7):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
If $\exists\ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}x_{n} = s > 0$:
$$
s = \root{7s}\quad\imp\quad s = 7
$$
Also
$$
x_{n} - 7 = \root{7}x_{n - 1}^{1/2} - 7
= {7x_{n - 1} - 49 \over \root{7}x_{n - 1}^{1/2} + 7}
={x_{n - 1} - 7 \over \root{x_{n - 1}/7} + 1} < x_{n - 1} - 7
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$x = \sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\cdots}}}}}$$

$$x = \sqrt{7x}$$

$$x^2 - 7x = 0$$

$$x(x - 7) =0 \implies x = 7$$

Because $\sqrt{7} > 0$ we reject the $x=0$ solution.

Comment: It is very easy to have $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=0$ while $x_n\gt 0$ for all $n$; your reasoning for rejecting the $x=0$ solution doesn't work without a better convergence argument.

Comment: I did an experiment. $\sqrt(7) < \sqrt{7\sqrt{7}} < \sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7}}}$

Comment: $$\sqrt{n} < \sqrt{n \sqrt{n}}$$