# $\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\cdots}}}=2$

Tags: calculus

Show that $$\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\cdots}}}=2$$
$$\sqrt{2}=\mathbf{2}^{1/2}$$
$$\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}}=\mathbf{2}^{1/2+1/2^2}$$
$$\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}}}=\mathbf{2}^{1/2+1/2^2+1/2^3}$$
Show the limit of $$\mathbf{S}_{n}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\dotsb+\frac{1}{2^n}=1$$ when $n\to\infty$
$$\textbf{S}_{n}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+...+\frac{1}{2^n}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}\textbf{S}_{n}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+...+\frac{1}{2^n})$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}\textbf{S}_{n}=(\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+...+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}})$$
$$\Rightarrow (1)-(2)=\textbf{S}_{n}-\frac{1}{2}\textbf{S}_{n}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$$
$$\Rightarrow \textbf{S}_{n}(1-\frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\rightarrow\textbf{0}\quad\textit{when n}\rightarrow\infty$$
$$\Rightarrow \textbf{S}_{n}\rightarrow\textbf{1}\quad\textit{when n}\rightarrow\infty$$
$$\Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty}\textbf{2}^{\textbf{S}_{n}}=2\quad\textit{when n}\rightarrow\infty$$

Comment: See this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/589288/sqrt7-sqrt7-sqrt7-sqrt7-sqrt7-cdots-approximation

Comment: I started reformatting this but it's too big a job. Please don't embed your text in MathJax formulas. That's not how things are done here.

Comment: +1 for showing your efforts. The logic in your proof is fine. However, in some steps, the $\implies$ symbol has been misused. (e.g in the line "$\implies (1) = (2) \ldots$" and the line "$\implies \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \to 0 \text{ when } n \to \infty$" ).

Answer (score 3):

Let $x_1 = \sqrt{2}$ and define $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{2 x_n}$, then it suffices to show 
that $\lim_n x_n = 2$.  In order to achieve this goal show that the sequence
$x_n$ is monotonically increasing and bounded above (I will leave this for you to do).

Then the limit exists so let $x = \lim x_n$.  Then, using $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{2 x_n}$ and the continuity of the square root function, we get that $x = \sqrt{2 x} \implies x=2$.

Comment: @Mustafe Said.  $x^2 = \sqrt{2 x} \implies x=2$. Typo, I guess (and hope !). Cheers.

Comment: I corrected it, thank you Claude.

Answer (score 0):

Let S be your general term for a large value of n. If your square it you have S^2 = 2 S, then S = 2.

Answer (score 0):

It's more simple to prove that, let $\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}...}}=t$. Then, $t^2=2t \rightarrow t=2$.

Comment: $$\text{You assume}\quad\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2...}}}=\sqrt{2\sqrt{2…}}\quad\text{it is true for final term}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$T=\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}}}...\\
\frac{T^2}{2}=T\\$$
T is a nonzero real number so:$$
T=2$$

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is correct!

Here is a different proof.
 
First note that the sequence, let's call it $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$, can be defined recursively as $a_1=\sqrt{2}$ and $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2a_n}$. Then you can show that it is increasing and bounded above by 2, therefore it converges.
Its limit, $\ell$, must satisfy $\ell=\sqrt{2\ell}$, and therefore $\ell=2$.