# Solving an infinite product of consecutive square roots

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given $a$ and $b$ calculate $ab$
$$a=\sqrt{7\sqrt{2\sqrt{7\sqrt{2\sqrt{...}}}}}$$
$$b=\sqrt{2\sqrt{7\sqrt{2\sqrt{7\sqrt{...}}}}}$$

I simplified the terms and further obtained that $ab$ is equal to:
$$ab=2^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{16}...}\cdot7^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{16}+...}$$

How can I get a finite value?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/589288/sqrt7-sqrt7-sqrt7-sqrt7-sqrt7-cdots-approximation/589293#589293

Comment: @JoshuaSalazar This can be generalized for any $x,y$ inside the radicals, not just $2$ and $7$. See my answer.

Comment: See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/955190/11619) for more discussion about the convergence issues.

Comment: How is @Famkes second answer not obvious? What keeps us from immediately substituting $1$ for $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+...$ ?

Answer (score 34):

Assuming both nested square roots are well-defined, we have $a=\sqrt{7b}$ and $b=\sqrt{2a}$, from which
$ab=\sqrt{14 ab}$ and $ab=\color{blue}{14}$.

Comment: i would add something like $ab \neq 0$

Comment: @Ben: I think it is trivial that if $a$ and $b$ are well defined they are positive, so $ab$ is positive as well.

Comment: It surely isn't hard to show that $a,b>0$, but by definition a squareroot can be $0$.

Answer (score 21):

**First answer**:

Notice that:

$$\color{Blue}{a=\sqrt{7\sqrt{2\sqrt{7\sqrt{2\sqrt{...}}}}}} \ \ \ ;$$
$$\color{Red}{b=}\sqrt{\color{Red}{2}\color{Blue}{\sqrt{7\sqrt{2\sqrt{7\sqrt{...}}}}}} \ \ \ ;$$

which implies that:

$$
\color{Red}{b}=\sqrt{\color{Red}{2}\color{Blue}{a}} 
\ \ \ ; 
$$

similarly we have:

$$a=\sqrt{7b} 
\ \ \ . 
$$

---

So we must have:

$$a= 
\sqrt{7b}= 
\sqrt{7\sqrt{2a}} = 
\sqrt[4]{98a}
\Longrightarrow 
a^4=98a 
\Longrightarrow 
a^4-98a=0 
; $$

but notice that 
the equation $x(x^3-98)$ 
has only two real solutions; 
$0$ and $\sqrt[3]{98}$.
So we can conclude that $a=\sqrt[3]{98}$.

---

Also we must have:

$$b= 
\sqrt{2a}= 
\sqrt{2\sqrt{7b}} = 
\sqrt[4]{28b}
\Longrightarrow 
b^4=28b 
\Longrightarrow 
b^4-28b=0 
; $$

but notice that 
the equation $x(x^3-28)$ 
has only two real solutions; 
$0$ and $\sqrt[3]{28}$.
So we can conclude that $b=\sqrt[3]{28}$.

---

So we have: $ab=\sqrt[3]{98}\sqrt[3]{28}=\sqrt[3]{2^3.7^3}=\color{Green}{14}.$

---

---

---

---

**Second answer**: 
Notice that

$$ 
\color{Green}{\dfrac{1}{2} + 
\dfrac{1}{4} + 
\dfrac{1}{8} + 
... = 1 } 
; 
$$

so we can conclude that $ab=2^1.7^1=\color{Green}{14}$

Comment: @ Jyrki Lahtonen  you are right. It need to attend some analytic conditions; which I have been forgot.

Comment: a,b = 0 is clearly an extraneous root that is incompatible with how they are defined

Answer (score 10):

$$a=\sqrt{7\sqrt{2\sqrt{7\sqrt{2\sqrt{...}}}}}$$
$$a^2=7\sqrt{2\sqrt{7\sqrt{2\sqrt{...}}}}$$
$$a^4=98\sqrt{7\sqrt{2\sqrt{...}}}$$
so
$$a^4=98a$$
and, assuming $a$ is nonzero,
$$a=\sqrt[3]{98}$$

$$b=\sqrt{2\sqrt{7\sqrt{2\sqrt{7\sqrt{...}}}}}$$
$$b^2=2\sqrt{7\sqrt{2\sqrt{7\sqrt{...}}}}$$
$$b^4=28\sqrt{2\sqrt{7\sqrt{...}}}$$
$$b^4=28b$$
and, assuming $b$ is nonzero,
$$b=\sqrt[3]{28}$$
so
$$ab=\sqrt[3]{2744}=14$$

Additionally, it's not hard to prove that if
$$a=\sqrt{x\sqrt{y\sqrt{x\sqrt{y\sqrt{...}}}}}$$
and
$$b=\sqrt{y\sqrt{x\sqrt{y\sqrt{x\sqrt{...}}}}}$$
then $ab=xy$.

Comment: Are you also one of those people who think that $1-1+1-1+1-\cdots=1/2$ because $S=1-1+1-1+\cdots$ satisfies
$$1-S=1-(1-1+1-1+\cdots)=1-1+1-1+1-1\cdots=S?$$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I don't see how that is analogous to this problem. The limit as $n$ goes to infinity of 
$$\sum_{x=0}^n (-1)^x$$
does not exist because of fluctuation, whereas this sequence does not fluctuate. I don't think my question deserves to be down voted because of my recursive definition - it is appropriate in this problem, but not in your example.

Comment: IMHO unless you **prove** that the limits exist, the answer is not useful.

Comment: What @JyrkiLahtonen means is that you need to ensure the given infinitely nested radical converges in some sense. This usually involves something along the lines$$a_1=\sqrt{b_1}\\a_2=\sqrt{b_1\sqrt{b_2}}\\a_3=\sqrt{b_1\sqrt{b_2\sqrt{b_3}}}\\\vdots\\\sqrt{b_1\sqrt{b_2\sqrt{b_3\sqrt{\dots}}}}\equiv\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$$If this limit does not exist, we would usually say the nested radical does not converge, though your solution ignores this.

Comment: Of course, proving the convergence is not too hard to do. Indeed, the related sequences here are clearly monotonically increasing, and by induction, bounded above by your claimed values, and thus convergent.

Answer (score 6):

This seems easier than the half page proofs people are providing

$$a = \sqrt{7  b}$$

$$b = \sqrt{2  a}$$

$$a^2 = 7  b$$

$$b^2 = 2  a$$

$$a^2  b^2 = 14  a  b$$

$$a  b = 14$$

Unless I am missing something, a > 0 and b >0 we already know