# Is there any mistake in my proof?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, nested-radicals

My little brother started fiddling around with his calculator, and noticed something curious:
$$
\Large \sqrt{a\cdot\sqrt{a\cdot\sqrt{a\cdot\sqrt{a \cdot \ldots}}}} = a
$$
So I went ahead and wrote a proof for it, which follows:

Let us consider the expression:
$$
\large \sqrt{a\cdot\sqrt{a\cdot\sqrt{a\cdot\sqrt{a \cdot \ldots}}}}
$$
If we rewrite the expression as
$$
\Large a^{\frac{1}{2} log_{a} \left(  a\cdot\sqrt{a\cdot\sqrt{a\cdot\sqrt{a \cdot \ldots}}} \right)}
$$
we can deduce that:
$$
\frac{1}{2} log_{a} \left(  a\cdot\sqrt{a\cdot\sqrt{a\cdot\sqrt{a \cdot \ldots}}} \right) = \frac{1}{2} \left( log_{a}(a) + \frac{1}{2} \left( log_{a}(a) + \frac{1}{2} \left( log_{a}(a) + \ldots \right) \right) \right)
$$
Then, 
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2} \left( log_{a}(a) + \frac{1}{2} \left( log_{a}(a) + \frac{1}{2} \left( log_{a}(a) + \ldots \right) \right) \right) &= \frac{1}{2}log_{a}(a) + \frac{1}{4}log_{a}(a) + \frac{1}{8}log_{a}(a) + \ldots \\
\frac{1}{2}log_{a}(a) + \frac{1}{4}log_{a}(a) + \frac{1}{8}log_{a}(a) + \ldots &= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \ldots = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n}}
\end{align}
And therefore:
$$
\Large a^{\frac{1}{2} log_{a} \left(  a\cdot\sqrt{a\cdot\sqrt{a\cdot\sqrt{a \ldots}}} \right)} = a^{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n}}}
$$
But since
$$
\large \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n}}
$$
is a convergent geometrical series, then we can say
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n}} = \frac{1}{2-1} = 1
$$
And finally:
$$
\Large \sqrt{a\cdot\sqrt{a\cdot\sqrt{a\cdot\sqrt{a \cdot \ldots}}}} = a^{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n}}} = a
$$
For all $a>0$

My question is, can I consider this proof valid? Did I overlook/assume something? I don't want to give my brother a broken proof for what he found.

I also wrote a generalization to this, but i won't write it in this question.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/589288/sqrt7-sqrt7-sqrt7-sqrt7-sqrt7-cdots-approximation

Comment: Thank you! Although you didn't answer directly...

Comment: your proof looks fine

Comment: Or just do $=a^{1/2+1/4+1/16+...}=a$ By the law of exponents