# Does $\sqrt{\cos{\theta} \sqrt{\cos{\theta} \sqrt{\cos{\theta\dots}}}}=\sqrt{1 \sqrt{1 \sqrt{1\dots}}} \implies \cos{\theta}=1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was solving this equation:

$$\sqrt{\cos{\theta} \sqrt{\cos{\theta} \sqrt{\cos{\theta\dots}}}}=1$$

I solved it like this:

The given equation can be written as:

\begin{align*}
\sqrt{\cos{\theta} \sqrt{\cos{\theta} \sqrt{\cos{\theta\dots}}}}&=\sqrt{1 \sqrt{1 \sqrt{1\dots}}} \\
\cos{\theta}&=1 \\
\theta&=\arccos {1}
\end{align*}

So the solution is $2n\pi, n \in \mathbb Z$.

Have I solved it the wrong way?

(The title originally contained a more general question: Does $\sqrt{a \sqrt{a \sqrt{a\dots}}}=\sqrt{b \sqrt{b \sqrt{b\dots}}} \implies a=b$? The current title is consistent with the body and the accepted answer.)

Comment: I see no particular reason for it to be true. After all, $x^2 = 1^2$ doesn't imply $x = 1$.

Comment: Take for example, $y=\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\cdots}}}$

Comment: $\sqrt{a\sqrt{a\cdots }}=a^{1/2+1/4+\cdots}=a$ and $\sqrt{b\sqrt{b\cdots }}=b$, so the implication is true.

Comment: If anything the ellipses should be inside the square roots: $\sqrt{b \sqrt{b \sqrt{b\ldots}}}$.  But "infinite expressions" are not expressions, and undefined unless some specific meaning is given to them using some appropriate limit (which of course must also converge).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

$$\sqrt{\cos{\theta} \sqrt{\cos{\theta} \sqrt{\cos{\theta}}}}...=1$$ 
$$(\cos{\theta})^{1/2+1/4+1/8+...}=1$$ 
$$(\cos{\theta})^{1}=1$$ 
$$\cos{\theta}=1$$ 
$$\theta=2k\pi,k\in\mathbb Z$$

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question in the title, let $A=\sqrt{a \sqrt{a \sqrt{a\cdots}}}$ and $B=\sqrt{b \sqrt{b \sqrt{b\cdots}}}$.

Then $A=B$ implies $aA=A^2=B^2=bB$ and so  $a=b$.

Comment: Why would $aA=A^2$?

Comment: @Man_Of_Wisdom, isn't $A=\lim a_n$ with $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a\cdot a_n}$ and $a_0=1$?

Comment: See for instance http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/589288/sqrt7-sqrt7-sqrt7-sqrt7-sqrt7-cdots-approximation.

Answer (score 3):

Another answer

suppose that $$\sqrt{\cos{\theta} \sqrt{\cos{\theta} \sqrt{\cos{\theta}}}}...=1$$
square both side you get $$cos{\theta} \sqrt{\cos{\theta} \sqrt{\cos{\theta}}}...=1$$
We know that $$\ \sqrt{\cos{\theta} \sqrt{\cos{\theta}}}...=1$$
thus $$\cos{\theta}*1=1$$
therefore $$\theta=2k\pi,k\in\mathbb Z$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$$\sqrt{\cos{\theta} \sqrt{\cos{\theta} \sqrt{\cos{\theta}}}}...=1.$$

Multiply by $\cos(\theta)$ and take the square root. You get

$$\sqrt{\cos(\theta)}=\sqrt{\cos{\theta} \sqrt{\cos{\theta} \sqrt{\cos{\theta} \sqrt{\cos{\theta}}}}}...=1.$$