# Find a limit of $\sqrt[3]{3} * \sqrt[9]{3} * ... * \sqrt[3^n]{3}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I have no idea how can i solve this. When i'm trying to transform a multiplication I always get a $0*\infty$ ambiguity.

I found only that

$\lim_{n \to \infty}{(\sqrt[3]{3} * \sqrt[9]{3} * ... * \sqrt[3^n]{3})} = \lim_{n \to \infty}(\sqrt[3]{3 * \sqrt[3]{3 * \sqrt[3]{3*...}}})$

**EDIT:** Solution
$\lim_{n \to \infty}{(\sqrt[3]{3} * \sqrt[9]{3} * ... * \sqrt[3^n]{3})} = \lim_{n \to \infty}(\sqrt[3]{3 * \sqrt[3]{3 * \sqrt[3]{3*...}}}) = \lim_{n \to \infty}{3^{(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{27} + ... + \frac{1}{3^n})}}$

$\sum_{r=1}^n{\frac{1}{3^n}} = \frac{\frac{1}{3}}{1 - \frac{1}{3}} = \frac{1}{2}$

So $\lim_{n \to \infty}{3^{(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{27} + ... + \frac{1}{3^n})}} = \lim_{n \to \infty}{3^\frac{1}{2}} = \sqrt{3}$

Comment: $3^{1/3+...+1/3^{3^n}}$

Comment: I do not think it is the best approach, but if $L=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\left(\sqrt[3]{3  \sqrt[3]{3  \sqrt[3]{3...}}}\right)$ exists then $L=\sqrt[3]{3L}$ so $L^3 =3L$ and so $L=0$ or $\pm\sqrt{3}$ or perhaps $\pm\infty$, giving $L=\sqrt{3}$ as the only positive finite solution

Comment: yes, it's more complicated than submitted solution, but also works fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

$$\prod_{r=1}^n3^{(1/3)^r}=3^{\sum_{r=1}^n(1/3)^r}$$

Now $\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^n\left(\dfrac13\right)r=\dfrac13\left(\dfrac{1-\left(\dfrac13\right)^n}{1-\dfrac13}\right)$^

Finally, $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac13\right)^n=?$

Comment: thank you, this is the key

Comment: Like https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/589288/sqrt7-sqrt7-sqrt7-sqrt7-sqrt7-cdots-approximation/589293#589293, another  form of the expression : $$\sqrt[3]{3\sqrt[3]{3\sqrt[3]{3\sqrt[3]{3\cdots}}}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Use geometric summation:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}{(\sqrt[3]{3} * \sqrt[9]{3} * ... * \sqrt[3^n]{3})}=\\e^{\log(\lim_{n \to \infty}{(\sqrt[3]{3} * \sqrt[9]{3} * ... * \sqrt[3^n]{3})})}=\\e^{\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum _{i=1}^n 3^{-i} \log (3)}=\\e^{\sum _{i=1}^\infty 3^{-i} \log (3)}=\\e^{\frac{\log (3)}{2}}=\sqrt{3}$$

Comment: You can make it a bit more simpler also...

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt[3]{3 * \sqrt[3]{3 * \sqrt[3]{3 * ...}}} = n$$
$$\sqrt[3]{3 * n} = n$$
$$3*n=n^3$$
$$3=n^2$$
$$n=\sqrt{3}$$