# How do I calculate $\frac{\ln(2)}{\ln(3)}\frac{\ln(4)}{\ln(5)}...\frac{\ln(2n)}{\ln(2n+1)}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, logarithms, infinite-product

The product has only positive factors so it has zero as lower bound. Also the product is decreasing as all its factors are less than one. In conclusion the series must have a limit. I also compute the first 150 values of the product and I got around 0.297. I believe that the product converges very, very, slowly to zero, but I can't prove it.

Comment: It is bounded by zero (positive) and continuously decreasing, so it should converge to zero, no?

Comment: @user1952500 so is the sequence $a_n = (n + 1)/n$

Comment: @TrevorGunn, do you mean the $\sum_{\infty} a_n$? I am talking about the $\Pi_{\infty}a_{n}$ here.

Comment: By the way, we do not say products converge to zero, but rather, we say the diverge to zero. Zero of products are the $-\infty$ of sums.

Comment: @user1952500 just the sequence. It doesn't matter if a sequence comes from a product or is by itself the conclusion is the same: just because a sequence is decreasing and bounded bellow by $c$ doesn't mean the sequence converges to $c$.

Comment: @TrevorGunn I think the two are different and please correct me if I am wrong. In the case of your sequence, $\Pi_\infty a_n$ would _not_ be a decreasing sequence.

Comment: @user1952500 $\prod_\infty a_n$ is not a sequence.

Comment: @TrevorGunn, but $S_n = \Pi_{k=1}^n a_k$ is, and is a sequence bounded by $c$ and is continuously decreasing. Do you have an example of an $a_k$ where $c \ne 0$ ?

Comment: @user1952500 $a_n = (n + 1)/n$ is bounded below by $0$ and continuously decreasing but $a_n \to 1$ not $0$.

Comment: @TrevorGunn I think I should ask a question to clarify the whole point. I am talking about the convergence / divergence of $S_n = \Pi_{k=1}^n a_n$ here. For the $a_n$ you mention, $S_n$ is continuously _increasing_.

Comment: @user1952500 Take $a_n = 1 - \frac{1}{n^2}$ then $S_n = \prod_{k=2}^n a_k \to \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @Winther thanks for that example!

Comment: @TrevorGunn thanks for pointing out the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just read [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1453665/how-to-calculate-the-this-limit-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-prod-i-1) and basically we can use the same approach.

If we denote
$$P_n=\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{ln(2i)}{ln(2i+1)} \ and \ Q_n=\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{ln(2i+1)}{ln(2i+2)} \ then \  P_n*Q_n = \frac{ln(2)}{ln(2n+2)} \, now \ Q_n \ge P_n \ge 0 \\
thus
\ 0 \le P_n \le \sqrt{\frac{ln(2)}{ln(2n+2)}}$$

Answer (score 7):

The given product equals
$$\exp\sum_{n\geq 1}\log\frac{\log(2n)}{\log(2n+1)}=\exp\sum_{n\geq 1}-\int_{2n}^{2n+1}\frac{dx}{x\log x}\\=\exp\left[C-\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{1}{(2n+\eta_n)\log(2n+\eta_n)}\right]$$
with $\eta_n\in(0,1)$ by the mean value theorem. Since both the series $\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{1}{(2n+1)\log(2n+1)}$ and $\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{1}{2n\log(2n)}$ are divergent by Cauchy's condensation test, the given product is convergent to zero, albeit very slowly.

Answer (score 6):

Hint:

Since

$$\ln(1+x)\sim_0x$$

It follows from logarithmic rules that

$$\frac{\ln(2n+1)}{\ln(2n)}=1+\frac{\ln(1+1/2n)}{\ln(2n)}\sim_\infty1+\frac1{2n\ln(2n)}$$

Reciprocate the product, then take the log of it, and with this, we find

$$-\ln\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\ln(2k)}{\ln(2k+1)}\sim\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{2n\ln(2n)}=+\infty$$

Thus, the given product should go to

$$\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\ln(2k)}{\ln(2k+1)}=e^{-\infty}=0$$

This approach may be rigorously done using squeezing and the bounds

$$x\ln(2)<\ln(1+x)<x\quad\forall x\in(0,1)$$

Answer (score 5):

$$\ln \left(\dfrac{\ln(2n)}{\ln(2n+1)}\right) \sim \ln\left(1 - \frac{1}{2 n \ln(n)}\right) \sim - \frac{1}{2 n \ln(n)}$$
and $\sum_n \frac{1}{n \ln(n)}$ diverges, so the limit is $0$.