# "Convergence"/"Divergence" of $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1 - \gamma_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, infinite-product

While trying to understand a proof of a result in an article, I stumbled upon the product

$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1 - \gamma_n)$$

with $\gamma_n$ a real scalar belonging to $(0,1)$. I'm not really a mathematician, so I looked through some of the articles here about infinite products (like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324650/convergence-divergence-of-infinite-product), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219109/convergence-of-an-infinite-product-prod-k-1-infty-1-frac12k?rq=1) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18179/finding-value-of-the-infinite-product-prod-bigl1-frac1n2-bigr?rq=1)), but got lost in the discussions about convergence and divergence to zero. What I would like to know is what are the conditions on $\gamma_n$ for the product to **converge/diverge to zero** as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Intuitively, I had thought that since $1 - \gamma_n < 1$, convergence was guaranteed, but [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141705/result-of-the-product-0-9-times-0-99-times-0-999-times?lq=1) showed me it may not be that simple. All the other questions I cited are interested in when does the product converges to a nonzero limit, but I want to know when does it go to zero... Is it really obvious and that's why nobody asks this question (or maybe I didn't find the right one...)? If you could please also point me to a reference of any needed theorem or result that might be needed or useful, it would be really great.

Thanks to all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition is that if 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty γ_n=\infty
$$
then the product is zero. This can be relatively easy be seen by taking the logarithm or using
$$
1-x\le e^{-x}.
$$

---

On the other hand, it is easy to generalize Bernoulli's inequality to get
$$
\prod_{n=N}^\infty (1-γ_n)\ge 1-\sum_{n=N}^\infty γ_n
$$
so if the series converges one can find an $N$ such that the remainder is smaller than $1/2$ and thus
$$
\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-γ_n)\ge\frac12\prod_{n=1}^{N-1} (1-γ_n)>0.
$$

Comment: Alternatively, we can use $e^{(-2\log2)x}\le 1-x \le e^{-x}$ for $x\in [0,\frac{1}{2}]$ to get the two-sided inequality in one hit. Given that $\gamma_n\to0$, we know that we'll eventually have $\gamma_n\le\frac{1}{2}$, so this works fairly well.